# duvida para consumir api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restful

tenho o seguinte serviço:

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("save")]
    public async Task<dynamic> save(VendaModel[] venda, string CnpjEstab)
    {
        dynamic retorno = null;
        VendaModel ultima = new VendaModel();

       //TODO   
    }
```

estou tentando consumir da seguinte forma:

```
public async static void SalvarArray(dynamic venda, string CnpjEstab)
    {
        string retorno;
        try
        {
            var url = UrlBase.urlBase + "/GetVendas/save";
            var a = new { venda, CnpjEstab };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);

            var stringContent = new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpClient req = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage resp = await req.PostAsync(url, stringContent);

            if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                retorno = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            GeraLogError.GeraLog("GetVendas", MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, err.Message);
            retorno = err.Message;
        }

        //return retorno;
    }
```

mas nao esta dando certo, a aplicação simplesmente é abortada (sem nenhum aviso) , não cai no debug da Api, tem algo errado no codigo ?

estou usando C#

Comment: Olá, amigo! Antes de tentar te ajudar, para descartarmos qualquer problema nesse sentido, a API está funcionando e no ar? Se sim, pode deixar explícito onde o seu debug é interrompido?

Comment: olá, esta funcionando sim, modifiquei o metodo para receber apenas uma string, e testei com postman, funcionou certinho.  O Debug é interrponpido nessa linha:  HttpResponseMessage resp = await req.PostAsync(url, stringContent);, aqui para e nao faz mais nada, nao chega na api, nao da mensagem de erro, simplesmente para.

Comment: A sua var url e está com que valor após a concatenação?

Comment: esta assim: http://localhost:64785/GetVendas/save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entendi. Se você quiser sincronicamente, não é necessário chamar wait(), apenas retornar Result diretamente. O resultado bloqueia o thread de chamada até que a tarefa seja concluída. Neste caso, até que o post esteja definido, você pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
var serializedVendas = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var content = new StringContent(serializedVendas, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = client.PostAsync ("api/vendas", content).Result;
```

Acabei de testar com uma aplicação exemplo e funcionou. Tive que criar uma api fake e um console application para entender o que estava acontecendo com o seu teste.
Boa sorte.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: opa, deu certo, mas ai vem uma duvida, esse serviço será consumido por muitos clientes, digamos uns mil clientes ao mesmo tempo, enquanto um cliente esta consumindo o serviço, os demais clientes ficam na fila(quando não é assincrono), correto? isso não geraria um time out?

Comment: OPA, fiz confusão, o metodo da api que tem q ser assincrono. Obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Olá, amigo! A sua API encontra-se em uma url X e você precisa explicitar isso no código.
Exemplo:

```
req.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000/"); //para uma api com esse caminho.
req.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")
            );
var serializedVendas = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var content = new StringContent(serializedVendas, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await req.PostAsync("api/vendas", content); //caso essa seja sua rota
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,

Comment: tentei como sugeriu, mas para nessa linha aki:      var result = await req.PostAsync("/GetVendas/save", content); //, nao chega na api, nao faz nada.

Comment: Acredito que a sua rota esteja errada. O post deve ser realizado em cima de uma rota válida. Exemplo: https://localhost:5000/api/usuarios passando um content formatado para ele. Acredito que sua rota esteja com algum erro. Qual a sua rota inteira ou qual rota você está pretendendo alcançar? Pode informar qual endereço você testou no Postman?

Comment: usei assim no postman: http://localhost:64785/GetVendas/Save?venda=sdasd, deu certo (lembrando q para esse teste mudei o metodo save para receber apenas uma string, )

Comment: Pode incluir a rota aassinada na controller da sua api? Exemplo:  `[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]`